# .Net Core Docker is deleting images(pictures) while building it on DigitalOcean

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

I have deployed .net core 3.1 project on DigitalOcean using docker. In my project inside wwwroot directory, there is an images directory where I am uploading my pictures. After uploading, I can see pictures in the browser.

But the problem is if I am building a docker project again and running it then it doesn't show the pictures which have been previously uploaded.

My docker build command is: `docker build -t "jugaadhai-service" --file Dockerfile .`
and docker run command is `docker run -it -d -p 0.0.0.0:2900:80 jugaadhai-service`

**EDIT 1:**  After some searching I came to know that when project is running through docker then files are getting uploaded in docker's containers directory not in projects directory. That's why images are not coming on new build.

Answer (score 0):

So when a docker container is created, it's an isolated virtual environment running on a host machine. If the host machine is your local computer or some host in the cloud does not really matter, it works the same way. The container is created from the build definition in the Dockerfile.
This means you can replicate this on your local environment, try build the image, upload a few images and then delete the image or create a new image with the same tag. The images are also gone then.

If you upload images or file to a container on let's say DigitalOcean, and you redeploy a new container with a different `tag`, the images still lives inside the old container. Same thing if you run on let's say kubernetes, if a pod/container restart has happen, again everything is lost forever and it's as if a new container was built.

This is where `volumes` comes in to play. So when you have persistent data you want to store, you should store them **outside** of the container itself. If you want to store the images on the host machine or some other network drive, you have to specify that and map it with the container.

You can find out more about it here:

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxi0CR2lCUc
- https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/understanding-docker-volumes-with-an-example-d898cb5e40d7

Comment: Thanks, @Henkolicious you have guided in the right direction but now the problem is even after creating Volume, I am seeing nothing is going inside a volume. Might be I am still missing something. 
Can you verify whether my command is right or not: 
**docker run -it -d -v image-volume:/var/service/JugaadHaiService -p 0.0.0.0:2900:80 jugaadhai-service**